Voltage regulating circuit for high frequency signal
I have a running circuit with an AD9833 to generate a sine wave with a desired frequency and phase, now I also want to digitally (not just a mechanical potentiometer) control the amplitude. The output of the AD9833 is 0.6 V and I would be satisfied if I could just set it at 0.3, 0.4, 0.5 and 0.6 V.
The sine wave is at a relatively high frequency of 1 - 2 MHz, which might cause problems with digital potentiometers.
I had some transistors laying around and wanted to try to build something like a power sink, however this created noise on the signal. See the following circuit (with a BC547 and 1 kΩ resistor):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I think what you should implement is a voltage divider, perhaps with switchable shunt resistors such that you pick your desired amplitude, you also need a series resistor whise value is larger than the output impedance of your network.

You need a variable gain amplifier (VGA) or digital potentiometer or some resistor network (to change amplitude in steps). In VGA the JFet ohmic region can be used.

As an experiment, maybe if you forced a DC voltage at the COMP pin of the 9833 it might alter the output amplitude from the internal DAC. I'm not definitely saying it will of course and, you must use a voltage that is less than the open circuit voltage on that pin.

@Andyaka Nice idea, but I use the AD9833 which is soldered to 7 pins (V_cc, GND, SDATA, SCLK, FSYNC, AGND, Output) so I doubt I can access the COMP pin
